# pandas to_sql function producing multiple indices instead of a hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following example CSV file:

```
AlignmentId,Classifier,Value
aln1,classifier1,True
aln1,classifier2,False
aln2,classifier1,True
```

Which should be uniquely keyed by the tuple `(AlignmentId, Classifier)`, and I want to load this to SQL, with this hierarchical index. When I do so, pandas instead produces two (non unique) indices:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=[0, 1])
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
df.to_sql('test', con)
```

If I go to sqlite table, and ask the schema:

```
sqlite> .open test.db
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test (
    "AlignmentId" TEXT,
    "Classifier" TEXT,
    "Value" BOOLEAN,
    CHECK ("Value" IN (0, 1))
);
CREATE INDEX "ix_test_Classifier" ON test ("Classifier");
CREATE INDEX "ix_test_AlignmentId" ON test ("AlignmentId");
sqlite>
```

Why is this not producing the hierarchical index? I have some legacy code that appears to work similarly, and when I check that database schema I instead see

```
CREATE INDEX "ix_BALB_cJ_cgp_CgpId_EnsId"ON "BALB_cJ_cgp" ("CgpId","EnsId");
```

EDIT: On further analysis, this appears to be the difference between using `sqlalchemy` as the connection engine and using the legacy `sqlite3` package.

So, this question may be rephrased 'How do I get SQLAlchemy to produce such a hierarchical index?'